# MySql find how many children a parent has

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find how many children a parent has, from the data below. Here `level` is the `level` and parent is the `id` of the `row` it's linked to. I'm trying to get data outputted, arranged by level and the number of children.

I pieced the below sql, but this doesn't really return results the way I want:

```
select id, level, count(parent) as p, country 
  from stats group by level order by level asc, p desc;
```

Can you help?

**Table Data**

```
"id"    "level" "parent"    "country"
"1"     "1"     "0"         "US"
"2"     "2"     "1"         "US"
"3"     "2"     "1"         "US"
"4"     "2"     "1"         "US"
"5"     "2"     "1"         "US"

"6"     "3"     "2"         "US"
"7"     "3"     "2"         "US"

"8"     "1"     "0"         "US"

"9"     "2"     "8"         "US"
"10"    "2"     "8"         "US"
"11"    "2"     "8"         "US"

"12"    "3"     "9"         "US"
"13"    "3"     "9"         "US"
"14"    "3"     "9"         "US"

"15"    "3"     "10"        "US"
"16"    "3"     "10"        "US"
"17"    "3"     "10"        "US"
"18"    "3"     "10"        "US"
```

**Desired Output**

```
"id"    "type"  "country"   "Count"
"1"     "1"     "US"        "4"
"8"     "1"     "US"        "3"
"10"    "2"     "US"        "4"
"9"     "2"     "US"        "3"
"2"     "2"     "US"        "2"
```

Comment: This looks similiar, you can find something helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682781/mysql-count-all-children-no-matter-how-many-there-are

Comment: The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.level, s.country, x.cnt 
FROM stats s, 
(SELECT DISTINCT(parent), COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM stats GROUP BY parent) x 
WHERE s.id = x.parent ORDER BY s.parent;
```

This way, it's ordered to show the higher from the hierarchy first.

Answer (score 0):

Get a count grouped by parents and join that back to the list to get the other details:

```
select idt.id as id, idt.level as type, idt.country as country, idc.ct as Count
from stats idt
inner join
(
  select parent, count(id) as ct
  from stats
  group by parent
) idc
on idt.id=idc.parent
order by level asc
```

Comment: What is idc.ct in your reply? I keep getting `Unknown column 'idc.ct' in 'field list'`

Comment: fixed.  Missing an alias.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this - add your desired columns in SELECT part:

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  IF (p.number IS NULL,0,p.number) AS number
  FROM stats s
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        parent,
        COUNT(*) AS number
        FROM stats
        GROUP BY parent
        WHERE parent!=0
    ) p
    ON s.id=p.parent
  ORDER BY s.level ASC, p.number DESC
```